# C Pointer to a dynamic array of type int(*)[row] inside where row is unalocated inside of struct

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, struct, types

Basically, I want to have a struct where I can put data and an array.

I know the method of using int** and then malloc an array of pointer.
then malloc at each pointer.

But that's not what I want. The reasons is that technically, this would be slower because (something something caching).

Also, it allows the data to not be fragmented.

And if I get it running, I will have the definitive best way to create a dynamic 2D array that can be placed inside a struct.

Here is an example of the nearly finished code.

I know this is similar to already asked question, even similar to a question I asked early on, but what I'm asking for is a different answer.

(What is the best possible way to create a 2d array of arbirtrary size (row, col) on the heap (dynamic memory, malloc...), such that this array is a data type that can be contained within a struct. Bonus point if the data can be stored consequitively on the memory.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int  row;
    int  col;
    int *(data)[];
} iMAT;

iMAT* create_matrix(int row, int col) {
    iMAT* matrix = malloc(sizeof(iMAT));    
    int (*arr)[row] = malloc(sizeof(int[col][row]));    

    matrix->row = row;
    matrix->col = col;
    matrix->data = arr;

    return matrix; 
}

int main() { 
        int row = 5;
        int col = 5;
        iMAT* matrix = create_matrix(row, col);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: the data you dynamically allocate for the `data` pointer will outlive the scope of the `create_matrix` function either way, and it only otherwise contains two `int` values, so it may be more straightforward to return the `iMAT` by value rather than dynamically allocating it and returning a pointer.

Comment: Is it not slower to return an iMAT then an iMAT* ... also, won't the col, row be "killed" at the end of the function?

Comment: Whether it's slower or not is probably not something you should be worrying about at this stage. As for the data, the `iMAT` value is returned from the function. This means that the `row`, `col`, and `data` member values are returned. But `data` is just a pointer to the memory that was dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't compile because this struct member:

```
int *(data)[];
```

Is an array of pointers, meaning that this:

```
matrix->data = arr;
```

Is an assignment to an array which is not allowed.  What you wanted was a pointer to an array of unspecified size:

```
int (*data)[];
```

Note however that you won't be able to access the array members directly because the pointed-to type is incomplete.  To read or write members of the array, you'd either need to cast it to the proper type:

```
((int (*)[matrix->cols])matrix->data)[1][2] = 4;
```

Or assign it to a temporary of the proper type and use that:

```
int (*data)[matrix->col] = matrix->data;
data[1][2] = 4;
```